# Recibir datos desde dos actividades diferentes

Tags: java, android, activity, android-intent

Tengo una activity primaria que recibe datos de otras dos activity secundarias, cuando recibe los datos de una de las ativity secundaria, me borra los datos que tenia almacenados desde la otra. Para enviar los datos de las activity secundaria a la primaria necesito hacerlo con el método startActivity(intent) y esto me hace que me falle la app.

```
    //Codigo del boton guardar de una de las activity secundaria
    Button btnGuardar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGuardar);
    btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Repetición guardada con éxito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
            toast.show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(RepetirActivity.this, CrearEventoActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Repetir", datos);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

   //recibo el valor de la Repeticion, este codigo esta en el método onCreate
    Bundle bundleRepeticion=getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundleRepeticion!=null) {
        valorRepeticion = bundleRepeticion.getString("Repetir");
        txtRepetir.setText(valorRepeticion);
    }
```

Comment: "me borra los datos que tenia almacenados desde la otra" o sea quieres mantener los datos en la activity primaria ?

Comment: correcto, en la activity principal recibo datos de 2 fragment y de 2 activity, cuando recibo datos de una activity me borra los datos recibidos de los fragment al usar el metodo startActivity(intent), en realidad no me borra, lo que hace es crearme otra actividad. Necesito saber como mantener los datos en la actividad primaria que recibo de los 4 (2 fragment y 2 activity).

Comment: Tienes el livadata de android pongo como statica en algun lugar o un singleton. Escucha ese dato cuando inicie el activirty y actualiza en base a esos datos.